# Incorrect float:left behavior with FireFox 9 & 10

Tags: css, firefox, layout

We're having trouble with `float:left` behavior with what appear to be simple `<div>`s on Firefox 9 *(and evidently also Firefox 10).* Here's [**the screenshot**](https://screenshots.newclarity.net/skitched-20120205-173518.png):

[image]

The link to the currently misbehaving webpage is [**here**](http://postquisdesign.com/revostock-top-sellers/). If *(on the Mac)* the user zooms in or out it corrects itself but on first page load it displays this weirdness, and I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you apply clear:both to that div?

Comment: your page seems fine on my firefox 10

Comment: @XepterX. The client reported it was a FireFox 10 issue so I took his word. Hmm.

Comment: ah.. i saw the problem, not on a firefox but on a chrome if i zoom into the webpage or i change the resolution..

Comment: you might want to set a width to your container for the images to dynamically resize with different resolutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is presumably that some of the floats in the line above are taller than you think.  A left float will be up as high as it can and *then* float left as far as it can, so if that third float in the first line in your testcase is taller than the fourth and fifth one (even by fractions of a pixel!) you would get the observed behavior.

Comment: YES! You are a godsend Boris. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You have 108 HTML errors and at least a few notable CSS errors. Not all of the HTML errors apply to this or are important but, in all that, there were some that might. Some CSS errors definitely need fixing.

Comment: Thanks. That site is actually our client's site; we created the WordPress plugin to display the gallery. The client doesn't really understand CSS well so we were trying to help them. Are you saying that this would work if the HTML were correct?

Comment: Turns out the problem was as simple as needing a height attribute set on the gallery item.  This "validation errors are the problem" answer set me off on a wild goose chase and wasted countless hours, hence the down-vote. Thank goodness for @Boris Zbarsky's answer.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Fixing your mistakes is never a wild goose chase. Ignoring your mistakes will only bring you more pain down the road. In the future, others will advise you the same way. Until you learn that, you will always have problems.

Comment: They were not _our_ mistakes. We built a WordPress plugin and a user of the plugin was using it on his site. It was his theme vendor's mistakes that were generating all the errors, not our plugin. Our plugin just needed a height tag to fix the issue as @Boris Zbarsky so thankfully pointed out.